# Loaded bitmap has smaller size than the source png

Tags: android, bitmap, png, pixel

I have a png image of 280 × 558 pixels. But when I load it with

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources, R.drawable.image_name)
```

the created Bitmap size is 186 × 371.

That happens with the Nexus 7 using the images in the drawable-large-xhdpi folder. The ldpi and mdpi devices load their respective images in drawable-ldpi and drawable-mdpi correctly.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nexus 7 is not xhdpi, it's scaling images from hdpi to tvdpi

> Google Nexus 7          |      4.1        |  tvdpi (but will scale down your hdpi assets

See: http://blog.blundellapps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/

To load image without scaling, use the inScaled option of BitmapFactory.Options. Using these options, you can also scale to different dpi.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inScaled

Comment: But it is large. It's using the images in drawable-large-xhdpi not the ones in drawable-hdpi

Comment: @kepa, what this guy said is absolutely correct. The Nexus 7 uses images from HDPI and scaled them to TVDPI. And the size you're getting is the scaled size.

Comment: Is there any way to load the image without scaling them or I need to add bigger images in other to have the desired size?

Comment: I finally changed drawable folders names from density to size. Instead of using drawable-ldpi, -mdpi, -hdpi and xhdpi I'm using drawable-small, -normal, -large and -xlarge. That way the images are not scaled